# How to reload form (using existing code) in a "background" thread without changing the existing code?

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

I am dealing with an app (Win Forms / VS 2010) that loads a lot of contact data during its startup. That's working fine.

A new requirement is that this app (let's call it the main app ) can also show a modal dialog and in that dialog the user can view data of different contacts. But the main app (which is behind the modal dialog) would also need to load the contact data every time the user changes the contact in the modal dialog (as both windows can be visible to the user; making the main app invisible is not an option). So the modal dialog and the main app need to be in sync.

My question is: I would like to load the changed contact into the main app "in the background" in this scenario as that loading requires a little bit of time due to business logic being run every time a contact is loaded.

We have got the code for the main app that is used to load a contact into the main app out of the main app itself (i.e. executed on the main thread) and that is working well.

But how would I reuse that code when it is being executing on a separate thread (in the background behind the modal dialog)? My concern is that this code (that loads a contact on the main app) does a lot of GUI updates and ideally I wouldn't want to change all the GUI updates in that existing code to see e.g. if an invoke is required etc (because the existing code is now not executed on the main thread).

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM for windows form?

Here is what you need.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364485/MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel-Patte

Comment: MVVM is based on notification event, code already changed... :D

Comment: As written above, ideally I wouldn't want to change the existing code of the main app. Redesigning it is not an option.